# Brightness control issue

Tags: brightness, notification

Brightness notification control is not working on Ubuntu 14.04. I searched over google if there is any method to fix it but I can't find nothing which is working or reliable.

This is what I got from `/sys/class/backlight/`

```
acpi_video0  acpi_video1  intel_backlight  radeon_bl1
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
sudo sed 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="/' -i /etc/default/grub

sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `apt-get`? That program doesn't do anything without arguments. Instead one needs `sudo update-grub` to recreate the Grub menu file with the previously changed configuration option. Rebooting can be done through other means than `reboot`.